# Cerrado Logback Error en filtro Concurrente

Tags: java

estoy teniendo un problema al usar los filtros de *logback*, debajo les dejo la configuración de mi *appender*.

```
<appender name="console" class="ar.com.custom.logging.logback.UdpAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
            <expression>return formattedMessage.contains("Cadena no deseada");</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <addr>${logback.udp-ip}:${logback.udp-port}</addr>
    <layout>
        <pattern>\(${HOSTNAME}\) %d %-5level [%X{requestId}] [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg</pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Básicamente cuando ejecuto mi *webapp* con algo de 200 threads listos para escuchar peticiones y recibe concurrentemente varias peticiones este filtro genera una excepción en la clase:

```
ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluatorBase::evaluate
```

La excepción que se lanza es [InvocationTargetException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html).

Esto provoca que dentro del método `evaluate` de la clase `JaninoEventEvaluatorBase` contabilice 4 excepciones y des-habilite el filtro provocando que deje de filtrar para los siguientes registros a persistir.

- ¿Se puede evitar este comportamiento?
- ¿existe otro filtro por expresión regular que no tenga este comportamiento?

La versión de *logback* que uso es:1.1.3 (No es un tema de versión porque actualizo a la ultima y sigue pasando este funcionamiento)

#### [CERRADO]

El comportamiento que les describí al final es el correcto de la librería, desde nuestra aplicación *loggeamos* algunas trazas sin mandarle un mensaje (el mensaje que le llega al filtro es null) y por eso después de 4 repeticiones des-habilita  el filtro para no estar generando errores in necesarios. La solución fue enviar siempre un mensaje y poner un interceptor que asegure que todas las trazas tengan un mensaje definido.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el stacktrace completo del error que te aparece en logback? De esa manera nos sería más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Hola Luiggi, No hay stacktrace, el tema esta que al hacer un grep en el archivo de log notas que en llamadas concurrentes deja de filtrar esa palabra, y de ahi en mas el filtro queda apagado, Pude llegar a este punto debugeando la libreria de logback.

Answer (score 0):

A falta de la traza de error que nos de más información puedes utilizar la siguiente configuración usando expresiones regulares:

```
<appender name="console" class="ar.com.custom.logging.logback.UdpAppender">
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
    <evaluator>
      <matcher>
        <Name>regex</Name>
        <!-- tu expresion regular -->
        <regex>[Cc]adena no deseada</regex>
      </matcher>
      <expression>regex.matches(formattedMessage)</expression>
    </evaluator>
    <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
    <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
  </filter>
  <addr>${logback.udp-ip}:${logback.udp-port}</addr>
  <layout>
    <pattern>\(${HOSTNAME}\) %d %-5level [%X{requestId}] [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg</pattern>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

No se si te funcionara, pero bueno prueba a ver que pasa....